# @Inject doesn't work with FacesConverter

Tags: jsf, null, ejb, converters, inject

I have a Problem in my Project.
I have a xhtml-Website with elements that need a FacesConverter, but in this Converter, I need a Service to inject, but everything I red in this Forum and tried out, is returning null, so can anybody help me?

And thats the Code
The Website:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">

                <p:outputLabel for="seminar" value="Seminar"  />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="seminar" value="#{addSeminarPhaseController.seminar}"  converter="seminarConverter"   panelStyle="width:180px" effect="fade" var="s" style="width:160px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:selectItem  itemLabel="auswählen" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{addSeminarController.allSeminare}" var="seminar" itemValue="#{seminar}" itemLabel="#{seminar.seminarName}"/>

                    <p:column style="width:10%">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-theme ui-theme-#{s.id}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{s.seminarName}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Converter:

```js
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import de.basf.gshev.sucw.beans.SeminarBean;
import de.basf.gshev.sucw.services.SUCWService;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
@Named
@Getter
@Setter
@FacesConverter(forClass = SeminarBean.class)
public class SeminarConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private SUCWService sucwService;


    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length()>0){
            try {
                if (sucwService == null)
                    sucwService = (SUCWService) context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("sucwService"); // Also isn't working

                System.out.println("get " + context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("sucwService"));

                return sucwService.findSeminarBeanById(Integer.parseInt(value));

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        value.toString();
        if(value != null && value instanceof SeminarBean)
            return String.valueOf(((SeminarBean) value).getId());
        return null;
    }

}
```

So thats it, i hope ye can help me, thanks for it!
I also tried to create the Converter in the Controller, but then i get this Error:

```js
Expression Error: Named Object: SeminarConverter not found.
```

The Converter:

```js
package de.basf.gshev.sucw.converter;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;


import de.basf.gshev.sucw.beans.SeminarBean;
import de.basf.gshev.sucw.services.SUCWService;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
//@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name="seminarConverter")
@Named(value="seminarConverter")
@Getter
@Setter
public class SeminarConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private SUCWService sucwService;

    public SeminarConverter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length()>0){
            try {
                System.out.println("get " + context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get(SUCWService.class));

                return sucwService.findSeminarBeanById(Integer.parseInt(value));

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        value.toString();
        if(value != null && value instanceof SeminarBean)
            return String.valueOf(((SeminarBean) value).getId());
        return null;
    }

}
```

The XHTML:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="seminar" value="#{addSeminarPhaseController.seminar}"  converter="#{addSeminarPhaseController.converter}" panelStyle="width:180px" effect="fade" var="s" style="width:160px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:selectItem  itemLabel="auswählen" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{addSeminarController.allSeminare}" var="seminar" itemValue="#{seminar}" itemLabel="#{seminar.seminarName}"/>

                    <p:column style="width:10%">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-theme ui-theme-#{s.id}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{s.seminarName}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

the controller:

```js
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

import de.basf.gshev.sucw.beans.MitarbeiterBean;
import de.basf.gshev.sucw.beans.SeminarBean;
import de.basf.gshev.sucw.beans.SeminarPhaseBean;
import de.basf.gshev.sucw.services.SUCWService;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
@RequestScoped
@Getter
@Setter
@Named
public class AddSeminarPhaseController implements Serializable {




    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2356022465339358536L;


        private List<SeminarBean> allSeminare;
        private SeminarBean seminar=null;
        private Date beginn;
        private Date ende;
//      private List<MitarbeiterBean>teilnehmer;
        private DualListModel<MitarbeiterBean> teilnehmer;
        private List<MitarbeiterBean> sourceTeilnehmer;
        private List<MitarbeiterBean> targetTeilnehmer;

        @Inject
        private SUCWService sucwService;


        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            allSeminare = new ArrayList<SeminarBean>(sucwService.getAllSeminare());
            sourceTeilnehmer = sucwService.getAllMitarbeiter();
            targetTeilnehmer = new ArrayList<MitarbeiterBean>();
            teilnehmer = new DualListModel<MitarbeiterBean>(sourceTeilnehmer, targetTeilnehmer);

        }
        public Converter getConverter() 
        { 
            return   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createConverter("SeminarConverter"); 
        } 
        public void addSeminarPhase() throws Exception{
//          SeminarPhaseBean spb = new SeminarPhaseBean(seminar.getId(), beginn, ende);
            if(seminar == null || beginn == null || ende == null || teilnehmer.getTarget().size() <1)
                return;
            SeminarPhaseBean spb = new SeminarPhaseBean();
            spb.setBeginn(beginn);
            spb.setEnde(ende);
            spb.setSeminarId(seminar.getId());
            spb.setTeilnehmer(teilnehmer.getTarget());
            sucwService.persistSeminarphaseBean(spb);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wrote, below, that all i red in this Forum, hasn't worked for me, so I must have an other problem and i don't know what the different can be, just for that i need your help.

Comment: Hey BalusC, I edited my Question and Code, but it doesn't work, please look if you find now, what i can do more, thank you.